# Dataset for impact prediction in a container

Tags: classification, cart, unbalanced-classes

I have a sensor that captures when there was an impact in a container. With this i have a dataset that contains data of when the device communicated and there was no impact and when the device communicated and there was an impact. The problem is that the device always communicates if there was an impact and communicates at random if there was no impact.

What i want is for a user to check for his container and to tell the user the risk of impact in his container. Assuming good enough features, is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: the term of art you're looking for is "noisy labels"